# Measuring efficiency with an interaction in a Tobit model?

Tags: interaction, stata, tobit-regression, marginal-effect

I am interested in how to interpret outputs generated with marginal effects after estimating a Tobit model. I am using Stata 13, so I figured I'd use the command margins - which I find very helpful. However, I am still a little bit lost when it comes to interpreting the results. I am researching firm level data in regards to innovation output and would like to understand wether certain companies use innovation input (for example Research and Development expenditures) more efficiently than others.

I have two issues:

1. Making sure that I actually estimate efficiency. I am just not sure if I am doing it correctly.
2. Understanding why the marginal effects estimated differ so immensely.

To make things a little more tangible, I figured a simulate some data and analyze them accordingly:

```
***Generate simulated Data
 set obs 10000

*Innovation input = x

 gen x=rnormal()^2

*Company type (coded as a byte)

 gen t=round(runiform())

*Market environment (coded as a byte)

 gen m=round(runiform())  

***Functional form where y is dependen on x, t, m and an interaction of x & t

 gen y=2*x-3*t+4*x*t+5*t*m+rnormal()  

***Creating Tobit conditions (left censored at 0)

 replace y=0 if y<0  

*Tobit: Let yi be the observed var bounded from below and yi* the latent var

 tobit y c.x##i.t i.m##i.t, ll(0)
```

The results are the following:

```
Tobit regression                                  Number of obs   =      10000
                                                  LR chi2(5)      =   34127.61
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -11931.847                       Pseudo R2       =     0.5885

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   1.998063    .010324   193.54   0.000     1.977826      2.0183
         1.t |  -3.041505   .0390662   -77.86   0.000    -3.118083   -2.964928
             |
       t#c.x |
          1  |   3.989137   .0146597   272.12   0.000     3.960401    4.017873
             |
         1.m |    -.03655    .029291    -1.25   0.212    -.0939662    .0208662
             |
         m#t |
        1 1  |   5.030305   .0444715   113.11   0.000     4.943132    5.117479
             |
       _cons |   .0551857   .0235698     2.34   0.019     .0089841    .1013872
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      /sigma |   .9966572   .0080676                      .9808431    1.012471
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Obs. summary:       2298  left-censored observations at y<=0
                      7702     uncensored observations
                         0 right-censored observations
```

I intepret the results as follows. **x** has a positive and significant effect on **y**. **t** has a negative and significant effect on **y**. In this example, companies of the type 2 (i.e. where **t=1**) are hence less innovative. The interaction term however shows companies of the type 2 generate greater returns of **y** per unit **x** invested.

However, I have some issues interpreting the marginal effects.
To beginn with, I postestimated the marginal effect on the observed endogenous variable y (censored or uncesnsored).

Results marginal effects:

```
. margins, dydx(x) predict(ystar(0,.)) atmeans over(t)

Conditional marginal effects                      Number of obs   =      10000
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : E(y*|y>0), predict(ystar(0,.))
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
x            |
           t |
          0  |   1.310562    .021878    59.90   0.000     1.267682    1.353442
          1  |   5.351779   .0214539   249.46   0.000      5.30973    5.393828
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, dydx(x) predict(ystar(0,.)) at(m=(0 1)) over(t)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
x            |
       _at#t |
        1 0  |    1.17447   .0196007    59.92   0.000     1.136054    1.212887
        1 1  |   2.626861    .024471   107.35   0.000     2.578899    2.674823
        2 0  |   1.175705   .0195122    60.25   0.000     1.137462    1.213949
        2 1  |   5.033166   .0211266   238.24   0.000     4.991759    5.074574
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I interpret the output follows: Holding all covariates at their respective mean, company type 2 generates 5.35 units of y per unit x invested, whilst company type 1 only amounts to 1.31 units y per unit x invested. As such, company type 2 are on average more efficient. Moreover, this relationship increases as m increases.

Ploting the results via marginsplot results in the following:

[image: Marginal effects of x]

The plot shows the respective marginal effects of **x** on the observed variable **y** at **m** equaling **0** and **1** for companies **t=1** and **t=0**. It goes to show that the marginal effects are higher for **t=1** at **m=1**. Again, I interpret the results as the efficiency increasing as m increases.

However, the results go astray, when I am estiamting and plotting the marginal effects on the latend variable:

```
margins, dydx(x) at(m=(0 1)) over(t)

Average marginal effects                          Number of obs   =      10000
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : x
over         : t

1._at        : 0.t
                   m               =           0
               1.t
                   m               =           0

2._at        : 0.t
                   m               =           1
               1.t
                   m               =           1

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
x            |
       _at#t |
        1 0  |   2.012943    .010086   199.58   0.000     1.993175    2.032711
        1 1  |   6.010168   .0109178   550.49   0.000      5.98877    6.031567
        2 0  |   2.012943    .010086   199.58   0.000     1.993175    2.032711
        2 1  |   6.010168   .0109178   550.49   0.000      5.98877    6.031567
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, as I see it, the marginal effects of **x** on **y** remain the same - regardless of the level of m. Why is that the case?
This is further substantiated when plotting the result:

[image]

I just do not get, how this comes about.

To sum up:

1. Do I actually measure "efficiency" via the way forward displayed above?
2. And, can I show altering efficiency via the help of marginal effects the way I did in the first place?
3. Why do the calculated marginal effects differ?
4. Why are the marginal effects on the latent variable the same regardless of **m**?

I've been boxing around with this issue for quite a while now and I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Welcome to CV! On this site there's no need to say "thank you" at the end of your post - it 
might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site 
([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" and it means future 
readers of your question don't need to read through the pleasantries.

Comment: Cool! Strait to the point. I like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure your code corresponds to what you think you are calculating.

Stata manuals use a strange notation that seems to be the mirror opposite of many econometrics books. $y$ is the latent variable, and instead, we observe $y^*$, which is $0$ if $y \le 0$ and $y$ otherwise.

In a Tobit model you can have at least 4 MEs, three of which are:

1. The coefficients themselves measure how the unobserved variable $y$ changes with $x$. That is the `predict(xb)`, which is the default if you don't specify a `predict()` option in `margins`. These will be constant here for reasons I will explain below.
2. The marginal effects of the truncated expected value $E(y \vert x,y>0)$, that is among the subpopulation for which $y$ is not at the zero boundary. This is `e(0,.)` one below.
3. The marginal effects of the censored expected value $E(y^* \vert x, y>0)$ describe how the observed variable $y^*$ changes with respect to the regressors. That is `ystar(0,.)` below.

The reason you get something nearly constant is that the marginal effect of $x$ in (1) is approximately $2 + 4 \cdot t,$ which does not depend on $m$, only the level of $t$.

Here's how I would calculate each of these. Note that I set the seed at the beginning so that anyone who replicates my code will get the same result, and that I wrote the tobit covariates using a different factor variable notation.

```
clear
set more off
set seed 42815

set obs 10000
gen x=rnormal()^2
gen t=round(runiform())
gen m=round(runiform())  
gen y=2*x-3*t+4*x*t+5*t*m+rnormal()  
replace y=0 if y<0  

tobit y i.(t m)##c.x, ll(0)

margins, dydx(x) at(m=(0 1) t=(0 1)) predict(e(0,.))
marginsplot

margins, dydx(x) at(m=(0 1) t=(0 1)) predict(ystar(0,.))
marginsplot

margins, dydx(x) at(m=(0 1) t=(0 1)) predict(xb)
marginsplot
```

The other differences is the `over()` vs. `at()`. The former calculates the ME of $x$ for each $m \times t$ combo. The latter resets *everyone's* $m$ and $t$ and then calculates. You seem to use a mixture of the two. It doesn't really matter here, but it can in other contexts. Here are three ways of getting the same thing:

```
margins, dydx(x) at(m=(0 1) t=(0 1))
margins, dydx(x) over(m t)
margins m#t, dydx(x)
```

Also, you seem to use the `atmeans` option inconsistently.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A followup question: When does the specification over() make more or less sense than the specification at()?

Comment: @Joni When the ME is non-linear (as in 2 and 3 above), if you calculate it separately for each company type with `over(t)`, you may get differences in MEs that are due to differences in other covariates if those vary by company type. Using the `at()` option makes the comparison more apples to apples, since you are holding some or all of those other differences constant.